# NSwag cannot create Swagger of inherited controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, nswag

In my ASP.Net Core app, I am using NSwag to create my swagger.json file.

When I build my project, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB3073 The command "dotnet
> ".nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.20.0\buildTransitive../tools/Net70/dotnet-nswag.dll"
> run aspnetcoretoopenapi.json
> /variables:"input=\src\ApiGateway.Api\ApiGateway.Api.csproj,output=\src\ApiGateway.Api../swagger/ApiGateway.Api.json,configuration=Debug,documentName=Public
> API"" exited with code
> -1.
> ApiGateway.Api  \src\Cat.Infrastructure\Build\CreateSwaggerDocument.targets

My controller looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/[controller]")]
public class MyController : MyControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}/result")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        return await ForwardRequest(HttpMethod.Get, 
            "http://localhost/v2/result");
    }
}

public class MyControllerBase : ControllerBase 
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForwardRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, string url, object? body = null)
    {
        // do something.
    }
}
```

When I put the logic from "ForwardRequest" into the MyController and remove the inheritence, everything works fine.
When I start to use the MyControllerBase class, it breaks.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `[HttpPost]` or `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPut]` etc... attribute to you base class method as well but look the following examples down here

#### Base class

```cs
public class MyControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    public MyControllerBase()
    {
    }

    public async Task ForwardRequest([FromQuery] HttpRequest request, string url, object? body = null)
    {
       //enter code here...
    }
}
```

#### Implementation

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/[controller]")]
public class MyController : MyControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}/result")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        return await ForwardRequest(HttpMethod.Get, 
            "http://localhost/v2/result");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if that function is used by HttpGet, HttpPost and HttpPut, etc.? Does this still work?

Comment: And adding the Attributes, didnt change anything. The build still fails

Comment: Ohh, okay I see your problem now. Let me adjust my answer

Comment: I changed my topic to something else at work, but will come back to this problem and check your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The HttpMethod in the API endpoint parameter can be replaced with a string.

Note: I used [HttpPost] because "object? body" will be fromBody. It can be [HttpGet], but you won't be able to use it in Swagger.

```charp
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebAppTestController.Controllers
{
  [ApiController]
  [Route("[controller]")]
  public class MyController : MyControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("{id}/result")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
      return await ForwardRequest(HttpMethod.Get.ToString(), "http://localhost/v2/result");
    }
  }

  public class MyControllerBase : ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForwardRequest(string method, string url, object? body = null)
    {
      var httpMethod = new HttpMethod(method);

      return Ok();
    }
  }
}
```